# AttributeError: 'ArgDef' object has no attribute 'handle_data'

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow-hub

I am trying to run this example from tensorflow.org on my local machine [1](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/classify_text_with_bert), but gives me the following error:

AttributeError: 'ArgDef' object has no attribute 'handle_data'.

The problem appears in line:

bert_preprocess_model = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_preprocess)

Tensorflow Version:  2.4.0

I have searched in order to find a similar mistake, but unfortunately I have not found anything relevant

Comment: According to Tensorflow tested build configuration documentation, the latest TF version is `2.4`. From where you installed `TF 2.5`? I was able to execute above code in `TF 2.4` with out any issues. Can you try and let us know? !

Answer (score 0):

The version of tensorflow was 2.4, I made a typo unfortunately.

But I overcame the problem by adding the following lines of code:

```
os.environ["TFHUB_CACHE_DIR"] = "gs://my-bucket/tfhub-modules-cache"
Bert_Model_Path = '______path to the downloaded model_______'
bert_layer = hub.KerasLayer(Bert_Model_Path, trainable=True)
```